# How to check if hyperlinked file has the correct file path

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a program that prompts the user to select a document from a file explorer window, that they can then rename to what they want, and it will show up as a hyperlink in the active cell, that on click, will open up the linked file. *However* I want to restrict the files they can link to a certain path (like this s:/folder/folder/folder/fileLocation). Here is my code:

```
strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.*, All Files", , , , False)
If strFileName = "False" Then
    Exit Sub 'Code that responds when the user cancelled and does not want to add a file to the database
End If

strShortName = InputBox("What do you want to call this link?", "File Name", strFileName) 'Prompts the user to insert
                                                                                         'the name of the file
If strShortName = "" Then Exit Sub 'Attaches the entered name to document

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=strFileName, TextToDisplay:=strShortName
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                    'The above code creates a hyperlink using the entered name and connects it to the document
                    'that was first selected to insert into the database
prompt2:
    strdate = InputBox("Please enter the date that you received this file in the following format: MM/DD/YYYY .", "date received", strdate)
    If strdate = "" Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Exit Sub 'Code that responds when the user cancelled and does not want to add a file to the database
    ElseIf Len(strdate) < 12 Then          'This code makes sure that the date is real and inserts it in the
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8) = strdate 'correct row in the corresponding column
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please enter the date in the correct format.")  'Message box that informs the user to insert correct format
        GoTo prompt2                                             'and restarts the prompt for another attempt
    End If

End If


Else
MsgBox ("You cannot add a document here.") 'This handles if a user enters code into a column that does not correspond
Exit Sub

End If
```

The solutions I have tried follow:

```
If InStr(1, strFileName, "s:/folder/folder/folder/fileLocation") = 1 Then
MsgBox "This is a valid location to select file from"
End If
```

and:

```
    If strFileName Like "s:/folder/folder/folder/fileLocation*"Then
    msgBox("This is a valid location to seclect file from")
    End If
```

Neither of these work at all.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Could try

```
If instr(1,strFileName,"s:/") >0 Then
    msgBox("This is a valid location to seclect file from")
End If
```

basically if search string ("S:/") is in strFileName then it will return >0

Answer (score 0):

Use / do access URL paths.
Use \ to access local paths.

Didn't you misplaced / for \?